# HTMLEditor subscript and superscript text

Tags: javafx

I have been trying to show subscript and superscript text in HTMLEditor. there are two buttons for sub and sup mode. the user types the (sub/sup)text in a textfield and press the OK button which allows the textfield text to be rendered as sub or sup in HTMLEditor. The code is as follows:

```
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;
  import javafx.application.*;
  import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
  import javafx.event.*;
  import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
  import javafx.scene.*;
  import javafx.scene.control.*;
  import javafx.scene.image.*;
  import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class HTMLEditorCustomizationSample extends Application {
// limits the fonts a user can select from in the html editor.
private static final List<String> limitedFonts = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Arial", "Times New Roman", "Courier New", "Comic Sans MS");

String sup = " ⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ᴬᵃᴭᵆᵄᵅᶛᴮᵇᶜᶝᴰᵈᶞᴱᵉᴲᵊᵋᶟᵌᶠᴳᵍᶢˠʰᴴʱᴵⁱᶦᶤᶧᶥʲᴶᶨᶡᴷᵏˡᴸᶫᶪᶩᴹᵐᶬᴺⁿᶰᶮᶯᵑᴼᵒᵓᵔᵕᶱᴽᴾᵖᶲʳᴿʴʵʶˢᶳᶴᵀᵗᶵᵁᵘᶸᵙᶶᶣᵚᶭᶷᵛⱽᶹᶺʷᵂˣʸᶻᶼᶽᶾꝰᵜᵝᵞᵟᶿᵠᵡᵸჼˤⵯ";
String supchars = " +−=()0123456789AaÆᴂɐɑɒBbcɕDdðEeƎəɛɜɜfGgɡɣhHɦIiɪɨᵻɩjJʝɟKklLʟᶅɭMmɱNnɴɲɳŋOoɔᴖᴗɵȢPpɸrRɹɻʁsʂʃTtƫUuᴜᴝʉɥɯɰʊvVʋʌwWxyzʐʑʒꝯᴥβγδθφχнნʕⵡ";

String subchars=" +−=()0123456789aeəhijklmnoprstuvxβγρφχ";
String sub=" ₊₋₌₍₎₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉ₐₑₔₕᵢⱼₖₗₘₙₒₚᵣₛₜᵤᵥₓᵦᵧᵨᵩᵪ";

char[] csup = sup.toCharArray();
char[] characters = supchars.toCharArray();
char[] csub = sub.toCharArray();
char[] character = subchars.toCharArray();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    // create a new html editor and show it before we start modifying it.
    final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(htmlEditor));
    stage.show();

    // hide controls we don't need.
    hideImageNodesMatching(htmlEditor, Pattern.compile(".*(Cut|Copy|Paste).*"), 0);
    Node seperator = htmlEditor.lookup(".separator");
    seperator.setVisible(false);
    seperator.setManaged(false);

    // modify font selections.
    int i = 0;
    for (Node candidate : (htmlEditor.lookupAll("MenuButton"))) {
        // fonts are selected by the second menu in the htmlEditor.
        if (candidate instanceof MenuButton && i == 1) {
            // limit the font selections to our predefined list.
            MenuButton menuButton = (MenuButton) candidate;
            List<MenuItem> removalList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            final List<MenuItem> fontSelections = menuButton.getItems();
            for (MenuItem item : fontSelections) {
                if (!limitedFonts.contains(item.getText())) {
                    removalList.add(item);
                }
            }
            fontSelections.removeAll(removalList);
            // Select a font from out limited font selection.
            // Selection done in Platform.runLater because if you try to do
            // the selection immediately, it won't take place.
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean fontSelected = false;
                    for (final MenuItem item : fontSelections) {
                        if ("Comic Sans MS".equals(item.getText())) {
                            if (item instanceof RadioMenuItem) {
                                ((RadioMenuItem) item).setSelected(true);
                                fontSelected = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!fontSelected && fontSelections.size() > 0 && fontSelections.get(0) instanceof RadioMenuItem) {
                        ((RadioMenuItem) fontSelections.get(0)).setSelected(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        i++;
    }
    // add a custom button to the top toolbar.
    Node node = htmlEditor.lookup(".top-toolbar");
    if (node instanceof ToolBar) {
        ToolBar bar = (ToolBar) node;
        ToggleButton supButton = new ToggleButton("x²");
        ToggleButton subButton = new ToggleButton("x₂");
        TextField txt = new TextField();
        Button okBtn = new Button("OK");
        Button clrBtn = new Button("CLEAR");
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        supButton.setToggleGroup(group);
        subButton.setToggleGroup(group);
        Separator v1=new Separator();
        v1.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        Separator v2=new Separator();
        v2.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        txt.setDisable(true);
        okBtn.setDisable(true);;
        clrBtn.setDisable(true);


        bar.getItems().add(v1);
        bar.getItems().add(supButton);
        bar.getItems().add(subButton);
        bar.getItems().add(v2);
        bar.getItems().add(txt);
        bar.getItems().add(okBtn);
        bar.getItems().add(clrBtn);

        okBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());
                if (supButton.isSelected()) {
                    txt.setPromptText(" Enter the superscript text ");
                    String text = htmlEditor.getHtmlText().replaceAll("</p></body></html>", "");
                    text = text.replaceAll("<html dir=\"ltr\"><head></head><body contenteditable=\"true\"><p>", "");
                    System.out.println(text);
                   text="<p>"+text + "<sup>"+ txt.getText()+"</sup></p>";
                   System.out.println(text);
                    htmlEditor.setHtmlText(text);
                }
                else if (subButton.isSelected()) {
                    txt.setPromptText(" Enter the superscript text ");
                    String text = htmlEditor.getHtmlText().replaceAll("</p></body></html>", "");
                    text = text.replaceAll("<html dir=\"ltr\"><head></head><body contenteditable=\"true\"><p>", "");
                    System.out.println(text);
                    text=text + "<sub>"+ txt.getText()+"</sup></p>";

                    System.out.println(text);
                    htmlEditor.setHtmlText(text);
                }
            }
        });
        clrBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                txt.clear();
            }
        });
        supButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (supButton.isSelected()) {
                    txt.setPromptText(" Enter the superscript text ");
                    txt.setDisable(false);
                    okBtn.setDisable(false);;
                    clrBtn.setDisable(false);
                }
            }
        });
        subButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (subButton.isSelected()) {
                    txt.setPromptText(" Enter the subscript text ");
                    txt.setDisable(false);
                    okBtn.setDisable(false);;
                    clrBtn.setDisable(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
private String convertSupText(String dsup) {
    char[] cdsup = dsup.toCharArray();
    String data="";
    for (int i = 0; i < cdsup.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < characters.length; j++) {
            if (cdsup[i] == characters[j]) {
                data = data + csup[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}

 private String convertSubText(String dsup) {
    char[] cdsup = dsup.toCharArray();
    String data="";
    for (int i = 0; i < cdsup.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < character.length; j++) {
            if (cdsup[i] == character[j]) {
                data = data + csub[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}

// hide buttons containing nodes whose image url matches a given name pattern.
public void hideImageNodesMatching(Node node, Pattern imageNamePattern, int depth) {
    if (node instanceof ImageView) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) node;
        String url = imageView.getImage().impl_getUrl();
        if (url != null && imageNamePattern.matcher(url).matches()) {
            Node button = imageView.getParent().getParent();
            button.setVisible(false);
            button.setManaged(false);
        }
    }
    if (node instanceof Parent) {
        for (Node child : ((Parent) node).getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            hideImageNodesMatching(child, imageNamePattern, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
  }
```

The problem is that after adding the subscript or superscript text, the cursor still remains in subscript or superscript mode and every time the text is added it goes on a newline.[image]

Comment: You haven't told us what you want the cursor to do.

Comment: @Nash As i have mentioned in the question: after I add the text as subscript the cursor should go to the normal size, but it still remains in the subscript size, which is the problem. hence, the normal text also goes in subscript which i dont want.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVP](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can try your code.

Comment: @Nash Sorry for late reply. here is the code that you can try and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thought so. I have done a work around using webview along with html editor. And it works fine for now. The code is as follows:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private HTMLEditor HE;
@FXML
private WebView WV;

WebEngine webEngine;
Button supButton;
Button subButton;
Tooltip sup;
Tooltip sub;
Alert info= new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    webEngine = WV.getEngine();
    supButton = new Button("x²");
    subButton = new Button("x₂");
    supButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                 info.setTitle("SUCCESS");
        info.setHeaderText("Information");
        info.setContentText("Use <sup>Text to to superscripted</sup> to use superscript fuction.\n Press Preview button to preview the changes");
        info.showAndWait();
            }});
    subButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                 info.setTitle("SUCCESS");
        info.setHeaderText("Information");
        info.setContentText("Use <sub>Text to to subscripted</sub> to use subscript fuction.\n Press Preview button to preview the changes");
        info.showAndWait();
            }});
    sup = new Tooltip();
    sub = new Tooltip();
    sup.setText(" Use <sup>Text to to superscripted</sup> to use superscript fuction.\n Press Preview button to preview the changes ");
    sub.setText(" Use <sub>Text to to subscripted</sub> to use subscript fuction.\n Press Preview button to preview the changes ");
    Node node = HE.lookup(".top-toolbar");
    if (node instanceof ToolBar) {
        ToolBar bar = (ToolBar) node;

        Separator v2 = new Separator();
        v2.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        bar.getItems().add(supButton);
        bar.getItems().add(subButton);
        bar.getItems().add(v2);

    }
    supButton.setTooltip(sup);
    subButton.setTooltip(sub);

}

@FXML
private void handleKeyTyped(ActionEvent event) {
    String text = HE.getHtmlText();
    text = text.replaceAll("&lt;sup&gt;", "<sup>");
    text = text.replaceAll("&lt;/sup&gt;", "</sup>");
    text = text.replaceAll("&lt;sub&gt;", "<sub>");
    text = text.replaceAll("&lt;/sub&gt;", "</sub>");

    webEngine.loadContent(text);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Manoj I think your problem is that you don't know what the `HTMLeditor` is doing with any text you enter in the textfield (aka `WebPage`). Appearantly it is applying the your `<sub>` tag to the next text you enter (adding <sub>1</sub> and typing a normal 2 afterwards results in <sub>12</sub>):

```
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p><br><sup>1</sup></p></body></html>
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p><br><sup>1<font size="2">1</font></sup></p></body></html>
```

I looked into the files (`HTMLEditor`>`HTMLEditorSkin`>`WebPage`>`twkExecuteCommand`) and in the end commands like bold/italic are executed in a dll (jfxwebkit). My knowledge is exceeded here. I see no solution which would not involve rewriting the whole `HTMLEditor` + native libraries.

(just included this in an answer bc comment length was exceeded)